# Understanding L3GD20 gyro output

Tags: gyro

Considering the following example in paragraph 3.6.3 (Example of angular rate data for FS=250) of STM's [AN4505](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/2c/d9/a7/f8/43/48/48/64/DM00119036.pdf/files/DM00119036.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00119036.pdf):

```
Angular rate values | Register address
                    | 28h | 29h
...
100 dps             | A4h | 2Ch
```

Does anybody can point me out how it comes that 0xA4 | (0x2C << 8) converts to 100 dps? I have already read both AN4505 and part's [datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/43/37/e3/06/b0/bf/48/bd/DM00036465.pdf/files/DM00036465.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00036465.pdf), but to my surprise, I couldn't find even a word about how exactly should we understand output register values.

Answer (score 1):

```
8.75 mdps/digit
8.75 = 35 >> 2
```

Is the conversion at range +-250 dps

```
This datasheet table has an error:
2CA4h =  11428 
C35Ch (should be D35Ch) = -11.428 =  -100 dps -> 8.75 mdps/digit
A6B7h = -22857 
5949h =  22857
```

1. new device L3GD20H, with better datasheet
   http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/35/b1/e0/39/71/57/43/01/DM00060659.pdf/files/DM00060659.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00060659.pdf
2. "library"
   github.com/pololu/l3g-arduino/blob/master/L3G.cpp

Offtopic: Please check pull requests  https://github.com/vdudouyt/stm8flash/pulls and merge?